# Form is not updating the amount of rows for a dynamic html table

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a dashboard php page with a dynamic table of records from mysql database, paginated into pages of 1000 each. I added a select dropdown with some options for the user to update the amount of rows displayed. The select has JavaScript code to automatically submit the form onchange.

Form Page:

```
<?php

 include('connect.php');

 // first check URL
 if (isset($_GET['amount'])) {
 $perpage = $_GET['amount'];
 }
 // Now check form
 if (isset($_POST['amount'])) {
 $perpage = $_POST['amount'];
 }
 // if nothing set, default:
 if(!isset($perpage)) {
 $perpage = 50;
 }


 if(isset($_GET['page']) && !empty($_GET['page'])){ // code to get the amount of records for HTML paginated pages
     $currentPage = $_GET['page'];
 } else {
     $currentPage = 1;
 }

 // Pagination code and query
 $startFrom = ($currentPage * $perpage) - $perpage;
 $totalEmpSQL = "SELECT * FROM `tblusers` WHERE Id NOT IN (1,2,3)";
 $allEmpResult = mysqli_query($conn, $totalEmpSQL);
 $totalEmployee = mysqli_num_rows($allEmpResult);
 $lastPage = ceil($totalEmployee/$perpage);
 $firstPage = 1;
 $nextPage = $currentPage + 1;
 $previousPage = $currentPage - 1;
 $empSQL = "SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Cell, Email, Address, Region
            FROM `tblusers` 
            WHERE Id NOT IN (1,2,3) 
            ORDER BY LastName 
            LIMIT $startFrom, $perpage";
 $empResult = mysqli_query($conn, $empSQL);

 ?>

 <!-- HTML Form -->
 <section class="panel">
 <header class="panel-heading">
             <div class="input-group">
<!-- JavaScript Filter Input -->
<input type="text" class="form-control"  id="search" onkeyup="myFunction()" 
placeholder="Soek lede..">
<div class="input-group-btn">
  <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
  </button>
</div>
</div>
</header>
    <div class="panel-body">

<div class="row datatables-header form-inline">

                            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">

                            <!-- THE FORM THAT IS SUPPOSED TO UPDATE THE 
VARIABLE FOR AMOUNT QUERY -->
                            <form method="post" action="<?php echo 
htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
                <select id="amount" class="form-control" 
onchange="this.form.submit()">
                                         <option value="10">10</option>
                                         <option value="25">25</option>
                                         <option value="50">50</option>
                                         <option value="100">100</option>
                                         <option value="500">500</option>
                                    </select>
                           </form>
                            </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <?php if($currentPage != $firstPage) { ?>
                        <li class="page-item">
                            <a class="page-link" href="?page=<?php echo 
$firstPage ?>" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Vorige">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">Eerste</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if($currentPage >= 2) { ?>
                        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="? 
 page=<?php echo $previousPage ?>"><?php echo $previousPage ?></a></li>
                <?php } ?>
                        <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" 
  href="?page=<?php echo $currentPage ?>"><?php echo $currentPage ?></a> 
 </li>
                            <?php if($currentPage != $lastPage) { ?>
                        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page=<?= $nextPage ?>&amount=<?= $perpage ?>"><?= $nextPage ?></a></li>
                        <li class="page-item">
                            <a class="page-link" href="?page=<?php echo 
  $lastPage ?>" aria-label="Volgende">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">Laaste</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin:20px;" 
href="index.php?page=new">Laai nuwe lid</a>
    </div>
</div>
        <!-- THE DYNAMIC TABLE -->
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="myTable" class="table table-hover table-striped 
    table-condensed mb-none">
                <?php
                    echo "<thead><th>Van:</th><th>Naam:</th><th>Selfoon: 
   </th><th>E-pos:</th><th>Adres:</th><th>Streek:</th><th>Aksie:</th> 
 </thead> 
   <tbody>";
                            while($emp = mysqli_fetch_assoc($empResult)){
                    ?>
                            <tr>
                                <?php echo "<tr><td>". $emp["LastName"] . " 
</td><td>". $emp["FirstName"] . "</td><td>". $emp["Cell"] . "</td><td>". 
 $emp["Email"] . "</td><td>". $emp["Address"] . "</td><td>". $emp["Region"] 
. 
"</td><td class='actions'><a href='index.php?page=edit&id=" . $emp["Id"] . 
"'><i class='fa fa-pencil'> Wysig | </i></a><a href='index.php? 
page=delete&id=" . $emp["Id"] . "'<i class='delete-row'><i class='fa fa- 
trash-o'> Verwyder | </i></a><a href='index.php?page=single&id=" . 
 $emp["Id"] 
 . "'<i class='delete-row'><i class='fa fa-comment-o'> SMS</i></a></td> 
</tr>";?>
                            </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- dash panel end -->




<script>
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables 
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("search");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
       if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
         tr[i].style.display = "";
       } else {
         tr[i].style.display = "none";
       }
    } 
  }
}
</script>
```

The page should load with the default amount of 1000 rows per page for the table, and then update when the select is changed to say 100, load only 100 records. It is currently displaying no records at all but when I remove the select it loads the default. My guess is, my code to handle the amount is not correct?

Comment: Normally you should **always** protect your query against SQL injections vectors with prepared statements.. Lucky for you PHP MySQL clients do not support multiple SQL statements separated with semicon and the MySQL LIMIT clause place can't really be attacked because it only allowes ints on those places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try assigning as a default like this:

```
$perpage = isset($_GET['amount']) ? $_GET['amount'] : 1000;
```

Currently you set it based on the `GET` value first, but then overwrite it in the next line. This way checks it's in the URL, and if not goes with your default.

Then add that amount to your paging links. For instance, change:

```
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="? 
 page=<?php echo $nextPage ?>"><?php echo $nextPage ?></a></li>
```

to

```
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="? 
 page=<?= $nextPage ?>&amount=<?= $perpage ?>"><?= $nextPage ?></a></li>
```

Also, your form is `POST`, yet the select has no name, so no value is posted. Plus, you  check for `$_GET`. So we need to tweak the select first:

```
 <select id="amount" name="amount" class="form-control" 
onchange="this.form.submit()">
```

However, this now means you need to check POST for the select yet GET for the paging links. So we now need to check which:

```
// first check URL
if (isset($_GET['amount'])) {
    $perpage = $_GET['amount'];
}
// Now check form
if (isset($_POST['amount'])) {
    $perpage = $_POST['amount'];
}
// if nothing set, default:
if(!isset($perpage)) {
    $perpage = 1000;
}
```

Comment: it works, it loads the default 1000 now, but now when I update the select dropdown, it reloads the page and defaults to 1000 again.

Comment: That makes sense, since the actual paging links don't have the number of records per page. Either reload page with the num per page in the url onchange of the select and use php to add that num to the links, **or**, listen for paging link clicks, prevent default, grab select value, append page number to url and then window.location.href to it!

Comment: could you give me an example please, I am not sure I understand you correctly for the above? <form method="post" action="index.php?page="$amount">

Comment: i'm not a JS expert but i could do it in jQuery

Comment: I can use jQuery as well yes please

Comment: Or just edit the `<a>` tags in your paging nav. Add the num per page to this `a class="page-link" href="?page=<?php echo 
$firstPage ?>" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Vorige">`, probably the easiest way

Comment: You see the code you gave works, the default is loaded when I load the page, but when I update the select, the value is passed to php variable for the sql query, but it defaults back to 1000 before the page is done loading. So I can click on say 50, it loads 50 records then while the page is loading goes back to 1000 again. Like its stuck in a loop

Comment: it does the same, changes to the amount selected in the dropdown then reverts back to 1000.

Comment: can you paste updated code so i can see what it's like now?

Comment: ...<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page=<?= $nextPage ?>&amount=<?= $perpage ?>"><?= $nextPage ?></a></li>...

Comment: i meant more the num per page part, i struggle to see how it could still be 1000 if you changed the assignment like i said

Comment: $perpage = isset($_GET['amount']) ? $_GET['amount'] : 1000; 
The amount variable is used in the sql query: $empSQL = "SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Cell, Email, Address, Region
FROM `tblusers` WHERE Id NOT IN (1,2,3) ORDER BY LastName LIMIT $startFrom, $perpage";

Comment: Updated, have a look

Comment: Still reverting back to default setting each time. I have an index page which stores location variables, could this page cause the problem? Example in index.php: if($_GET["page"] == "single") {
        $page = "singlesms.php";
        $title = "Stuur SMS";
    }
The dashboard page code above in fact index.php?page=dashboard.

Comment: can you edit your question, pasting the up to date code in its entirety?

Comment: i'm away for lunch but back soon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182647/discussion-between-andre-van-rensburg-and-delboy1978uk).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by a data tables plugin that came with Bootstrap. All I needed to do was add the class dataTable to the table and everything worked.